# Can I solve this problem using Gay Lussac's law of pressure?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas, adiabatic

*This question came in the Khulna University admission exam 13-14*

Q) When a tire is pumped at temperature $27^{\circ}C$, it bursts abruptly after its pressure becomes $2atm$. What is its final temperature $[\gamma=1.4]$?

(a) $27^{\circ}C$

(b) $-30^{\circ}C$

(c) $-26.9^{\circ}C$

(d) $26.9^{\circ}C$

**Third party question bank's attempt:**

$$T_1P_1^{\frac{1-\gamma}{\gamma}}=T_2P_2^{\frac{1-\gamma}{\gamma}}$$

$$300\cdot(2)^{\frac{1-1.4}{1.4}}=T_2\cdot(1)^{\frac{1-1.4}{1.4}}$$

$$T_2=246.1K=-26.9^{\circ}C$$

So, (c).

**My attempt:**

According to Gay Lussac's law of pressure,

$$\frac{P_1}{T_1}=\frac{P_2}{T_2}$$

$$\frac{2}{300}=\frac{1}{T_2}$$

$$T_2=150K=-123^{\circ}C$$

Why did I get the wrong answer in my attempt?

Comment: All the given answers are wrong.  The tire will heat up as it is pumped up.

Comment: @DavidWhite What will be the value T2 according to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third party answer assumes that the "abrupt burst" process is isentropic. When the tire bursts, the gas will expand (change the volume) until it reaches the atmospheric pressure. Because this process is fast (i.e. abrupt) it is also assumed to be adiabatic (no heat is exchanged with the environment) and with no losses (due to friction, sound, etc...).

Your answer (with G-L law) assumes that the transformation occurs at constant volume which is clearly false; moreover, applying the first law of thermodynamics will show that heat is exchanged with the environment. The latter is in contradiction with the assumption of fast process.